# How can I use and with in clause Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How Can I use **and with in**     in mysql like:-

```
select * from user where userId in (1,2,3) and (3,5);
```

this should return detail of only user 3

But I get error **operand should contain only one column**(which is expected)

//value (1,2,3) and (3,5) comes from sub query

Answer (score 3):

You need to repeat the expression:

```
select *
from user
where userId in (1, 2, 3) and userID in (3, 5);
```

`and` connects boolean expressions.  `(3, 5)` is not such an expression, but `userID in (3, 5)` is.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is lacking a target column in `and (3,5)`.

```
select * from user where userId in (1,2,3) and userId in (3,5);
```